# Memcached dump/export/migrate from one machine to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I need to take the dump of Memcached and move it from one instance/machine to another but there is no precise way/mechanism to do so like Redis. I tried MemcachedTool `memcached-tool localhost:11211 dump` but it misses some key-value, So please let me know what the best way to do this operation is?

**Note:** I have a Memcached instance on AWS Singapore zone which I want to migrate to the Mumbai zone.

Answer (score 0):

memcached dump is not a reliable approach since data per slab is limited so it misses a lot of key values. I chose a different path, I created a new instance(let's say M2) and took a dump of 1st instance(let's say M1), uploaded the dump in M2, and also added M1 in the fallback of M2(In my code, service layer)

Suppose there is a get call, the flow will be like

```
Obj value = get(key) on M2 instance
if(value is null){
   value = get(key) on M1 instance
   if(value not null){
      add(key,value) on M2 instance // it will maintain the data on M2 for next call
   }
}
return val;
```

The same approach will be followed for add/delete... according to use case

**Now the question is when do you delete/terminate the first instance?**

Suppose the max expiry time of the key is X days, then within X days, the data should be consistent on both instances M1 & M2. So you can terminate the 1st instance after (X + 1) day.

I hope this is helpful, if anybody needs more clarification of any scenario then message me.